# Php shell_exec() not running python script

Tags: python, php, python-3.x, web

I am trying to run a python script from php code. I have followed other threads to see what I'm doing wrong, but i can't seem to find the problem.

```
$out = shell_exec(escapeshellcmd("/path/to/script/here/script.py arg1 arg2"));
echo $out;
```

As you might ask, yes, the script:

1. has "#!/usr/bin/env python3" added
2. has permission to be read and executed by group www-data (from output apachectl -S)
3. is executable

At the same time, any other non-script command works just fine with `shell_exec()`

Comment: Have you tried adding "python3 " at the front of the command? so `"python3 '/path/script.py' args"`

Comment: I think `escapeshellcmd` is escaping all the `/`.  You don't need it unless that is coming from somewhere else.  If the args are then just use `escapeshellarg` on those individually, maybe.

Comment: @AbraCadaver surely you *want* the `/` escaped, given they're just text as part of the path, rather than anything special? Anyway, isn't it `\ ` that's usually the special one? XDead, what happens if you put the python file next to your php file so you dont need to include any slashes and can just call it by name?

Comment: @ch4rl1e97 I have just tried to place the script file in the same directory as the php file and the result is the same. Also adding 'python3' or '/usr/bin/python3' does nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried your code, it is working fine for me.
If there is some error, it must be logged in `error.log` file.
e.g. I am using apache so my errors are logged in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: Thank you for the response. Indeed, there are errors due to the fact that on the www-data user i do not have all python modules installed.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the problem is the permission with the module, in this case pydub.